# fdisk doesn't complete and hangs on a USB drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, formatting

fdisk problem.

OS: linux centos 7

I used fdisk on a usb drive. It has hung and I haven't been able to kill it or get out of it.

As an additional problem, since then, in trying to remedy this problem, I physically removed other USB drives that showed up in /dev/. However, those still show in /dev/ even though are no longer physically attached.

Here is lsblk  (I removed from this listing other devices that are listed)
 lsblk

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdf                       8:80   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdf1                    8:81   0   1.8T  0 part 
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I made the choices below following the notes I made when a friend formatted another USB drive for me (same exact USB drive type). The intention is to format it as ext4.

Below is the set of choices (emboldened):

```
[root@linux18 ~]# fdisk /dev/sdf
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
Command (m for help): **m**
Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create an IRIX (SGI) partition table
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help): **d**
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 is deleted

Command (m for help): **n**
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-3906963455, default 2048): 
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-3906963455, default 3906963455): 
Using default value 3906963455
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 1.8 TiB is set

Command (m for help): **t**
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 83
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux'

Command (m for help): **w**
The partition table has been altered!
```

Here I tried both Control C and Control Z:

```
^[[B^[[B^[[B

^[[6~

^C^[[5~
```

Comment: Could you post dmesg output right after it hang?

Comment: The fdisk command was invoked about 24 hours ago - I am showing here what I think it might be but am not sure:

[3398520.474203] INFO: task fdisk:31778 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[3398520.474208] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[3398520.474210] fdisk           D ffff88045fd13680     0 31778  21459 0x00000080
[3398520.474214]  ffff880013e17cc8 0000000000000086 ffff8800021a8000 ffff880013e17fd8
[3398520.474218]  ffff880013e17fd8 ffff880013e17fd8 ffff8800021a8000 ffff88045fd13f48
[3398520.474220]  ffff88045ff9cee8 0000000000000002 ffffffff811562e0

Answer (score 0):

This seem so be analogous to the problem you were facing: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/369623

Maybe try `# dmsetup remove` with some of the flag in the man page (`--force --deferred --retry`)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to force a rescan of the disks attached to the system as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404405/115876), e.g.:

```
echo "- - -" >> /sys/class/scsi_host/host_0/scan
```